# "Race" is to "racist" as "knowledge" and "disposition" are to what words?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

- *race → racist*
- *freedom → fascist* (for example)
- *knowledge* → ?
- *disposition* → ?

What's the word to describe a person who is disrespectful of your knowledge or disposition?

Comment: If you are truly knowledgeable then _irreverence_ comes to mind

Comment: `irreverence` is too vague in this case.   He's looking for a specific relationship between the words.  I don't know if those words *have* related words that specifically means disrespect.   The closest for knowledge I can think of is `ignoramus`, but that doesn't necessarily mean disrespect, though the connotation is definitely negative.   As far as disposition, I think `bully` would be somewhat appropriate.

Comment: If you are asking for a pseudo-scientific insult to hurl at someone who disagrees with you or corrects you (properly or otherwise), I think the question is off-topic.

Comment: *Race* is to *racist* is *not* as *freedom* is to *fascist* — this is a completely different *-ist*, as are the *-ist* s in *violinist*, *Marist*, or *Japanist*, for example.

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone that I had not requested an education but a one word answer to a simple question thank you

Comment: for the record mplungjan ragingcell and choster, I appreciate every word you wrote. I only detest unconstructive comments -who got flagged anyway

Answer (score 4):

**Racist** means "discriminatory against on the basis of your race", not merely "disrespectful towards". And **fascist** means a proponent of a specific political theory, not someone who is disrespectful of freedom. The answers provided above are valiant efforts, but there is really no answer to your question exactly as it's posed since it's based on incorrect assumptions.

My top suggestion for knowledge is probably **philistine**, someone who's uninterested in intellectual pursuits, or is smugly ignorant or indifferent to intellectual value. It's a bit of a stretch, but seems appropriate for the context.

You might also simply use **ignorant**, or there's a variety of terms for negative terms for "uneducated person" that could (again, at a bit of a stretch) be adapted to fit: **rube**, **yokel**, etc.

Also, people *will* debate the validity of a question in the comments; it's well within their rights here and the acceptable use of comments. Being hostile to people who question your question isn't appropriate.

Comment: ignornat might b appropriate but's least effective in that the user does not inflict any fitting aggression if it was hurled, at well, a philistine. Philistine was EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you, and that's what makes you and your answers unique for taking the time to properly understand the question. And for that I'm very (very) thankful. There's this cousin of mine, a non-English speaker, who proves to be such a lowlife because he (seems to) has a terrible grudge against my intellectual capacities and just for "speaking" English, not to mention being a profound user/Screenwriter.

Comment: Hurling Ignoramus (like yet another fitting solution above) or Philistine at him will have NO effect as he's engulfed in a sea of arrogance and disrespect towards that "he's not able to muster" but Yee-Lum's solution will help to address the situation if it was brought up. Thanks again :) peace

Comment: "the adverse actions of another could be a prompt to seek answers" someone great in the past should've said that, because it sounds cool and insightful. Such a strategy is what I realise now, used to learn a new word or two. This and many re the true path to spiritual progress. Anything and everything is obsolete however if you're not vegan period

Answer (score 1):

A racist believes that one race is inherently superior to others. One who believes that one level or branch of knowledge is inherently superior to another is an [elitist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elitist?s=t) or, more informally, a snob (or perhaps an intellectual snob). I am not sure if these terms could be used for disposition, however.

[Bigot](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bigot?s=t) could also be used, but it doesn't have the meaning of "X better than Y and Z because of inherent reasons" - it is "X is better than Y and Z because X is what I believe in".